# Mule 4 on-premise installation

Tags: mulesoft

I’m trying to deploy an API to on-premise installation of Mule 4 and getting an error that the ${mule.key} is missing. Now I need to update the wrapper.conf file. Has anyone done this before? If so, please share details on how you did it

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of properties is a basic task in Mule. There are several ways to do it explained in the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/configuring-properties#system-properties

To configure one in the wrapper.conf file you need to add a new line like the following one with an unique number for your file:

```
wrapper.java.additional.79=-Dmule.key=1234
```

I added a random number (79) as an example. You should check that it is not repeated for other properties definitions in the same file.